# Can CGPDFDataFormatJPEG2000 be used for something other than a JPEG2000 image?

Tags: cocoa, pdf, quartz-2d, pdfkit, cgpdf

Using the Quartz 2D PDF routines, can the `CGPDFDataFormat` format of a `CGPDFStreamRef` PDF stream be equal to `CGPDFDataFormatJPEG2000` in any case other than for an XObject image with a filter of `/JPXDecode`?

In other words, is the `CGPDFDataFormatJPEG2000` format ever used for anything other than JPEG2000 image streams? The reasonable answer would be ***no***, but there can always be a difference between common usage and what's theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPXDecode filter expects a JPEG2000 image file to be stored in the image XObject, not just compressed raw data. I can say 100% it is always used for image XObjects. But theoretically nothing stops you to wrap your raw content stream data as a JPEG2000 image and then use the JPXDecode filter with a regular content stream. It is just not practical.

Comment: OK, this is what I though was implied by the specification. Thanks for the confirmation!